# PascalAbc работа со списками , процедура добавления в начало списка

Tags: pascal, списки, процедуры

Есть процедура добавления нового элемента в начало списка. Kак мне задать его значение в начале, чтобы не ноль было. 
Процедура:

```
введите сюда код

procedure DobBNach(var L:TDList);
var
NewHead : ^TElem;
begin
  new(NewHead);
  NewHead^.PNext := L.PFirst;
  L.PFirst := NewHead;
end;
```

Comment: Кого - "его"? *Мать любит дочь.*

Comment: Новый элемент который я добавляю в список с помощью этой процедуры.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
procedure DobBNach(aData: TData; var L: TDList);
var
  NewHead: ^TElem;
begin
  new(NewHead);
  NewHead^.Data := aData;
  NewHead^.PNext := L.PFirst;
  L.PFirst := NewHead;
end;   

...
DobBNach(123, list);
```

Comment: Все работает спасибо вам за помощь.

Comment: Это я сглупил извините за предыдущие комментарии.

Comment: @ДенисЛобанов На здоровье. Молодец, что разобрались. Успехов!